# VPS disk size is much larger than expected (830GB instead of 80GB)

Tags: vps

We have rent a server and created a few VPS on it.  I have an VPS that I deployed some services on it, The amount of storage has been defined to 80GB and  10GB of the space is used.

Problem is that the size of VPS on the host is 830GB that it very strange. do you have any suggestion that help me find out why the size is this much different and how to solve it?

[image]
Thanks.

Comment: Probably a typo when you've created the storage for your VPS?

Comment: Thank you for commenting, I have checked again, it is not, we just Migrated from another sever and copied the VPS image to new server, since then it has this problem, shall I check something else ?

Comment: I would connect to the server (not the VPS) and check the storage and vm-104-disk-1 file size.

Comment: Could it be thin provisioned space? They provisioned 80 GB to you but make it look like 830.